# Å vs å is not matching in mysql query - how to do case insensitive match

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, mysqli, case-sensitive

I have a danish website developed in `PHP`. I am using `mysqli`.

I have the words like Daugård and Århus in database field called tags.

I want this both values as result when I run a query like below.

```
Query : select * from table_name where tags like '%år%'; 
Expected result : Daugård and Århus both
Actual result : Daugård
```

Right now its performing case-sensitive match and returning only Daugård word.
I tried changing charset to utf8 dynamically by function set_charset('utf8'), but it didn't work.

Collation for the `'tags' field is 'utf8_general_ci'`, `table collation is 'utf8_general_ci'` and my `database collation is 'latin1_swedish_ci'`.

Help me how can I achieve this?

Comment: Does the field have a collation of its own?

Comment: Yes I forgot to mention, the 'tags' field also have 'utf8_general_ci' collation

Comment: Is the data actually correctly stored in the database, as the characters Å and å? "Tried changing charset" sounds like you were not setting a charset before, which means the data may be stored as garbage in the database and MySQL cannot be aware of the specific character.

Comment: well I tried changing charset runtime while retrieving data via a PHP-MySQLi Query. I didn't changed collation of table, field or database before or after saving...

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: MySQL version is 5.6.17

Comment: Have you tried with SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE tags COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI LIKE '%år%';  ?

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the collation issue, use a case conversion function on "tags" before comparison:

```
select * from table_name where lcase(tags) like '%år%';
```

I might be missing something as MySQL isn't that familiar to me. I know the function LOWER(tags) does the job in Oracle as long as the pattern searched for also is in lower case.